# Resolving ESLint error due to `no-param-reassign` and `prefer-rest-params`

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resolve these two ESLint errors for the bit of code included below but cannot get my head around it.

```
9   error  Assignment to property of function parameter 'opts'  no-param-reassign
10  error  Use the rest parameters instead of 'arguments'       prefer-rest-params
```

And this is the code snippet:

```
 8  initialize(opts) {
 9    opts.hasStar = true;
10    AbstractResultView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
11  }
```

I have already tried these for the second error but so far no luck:

```
 8  initialize(...args, opts) {
 9    opts.hasStar = true;
10    AbstractResultView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, args);
11  }
```

and

```
 8  initialize(opts, ...args) {
 9    opts.hasStar = true;
10    AbstractResultView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, args);
11  }
```

As for the first error, I have no idea how to fix it...

Should mention that this is not my code (I am just trying to fix it) so I may be missing something...

Comment: That second line should probably be just `super.initialize(opts)`. (Or `super.initialize(opts, ...args)` if you want to support multiple arguments)

Answer (score 0):

The first error is here because in your eslint configuration you use the following:

```
no-param-reassign: ["error", { "props": true }]
```

Because of the `"props": true`, you can't reassign an object property if this object is a parameter of the function. Your choices here are limited. You can remove the line or change the eslint configuration.

More informations on this specific rule : https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign

You can have more information on the second error here : https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-rest-params

But according to the documentation, your second code (`initialize(opts, ...args) {`) should fix the issue.

Comment: I did look at the documentation and for some reason `initialize(opts, ...args) {` does not work for me... quite strange.

Comment: I found out why `initialize(opts, ...args) {`  was not working: it is because in the code `args` was expected to contain all arguments, including `opts` whereas with this approach it was getting only the remaining arguments, without `opts`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
initialize(opts, ...args) {
    AbstractResultView.prototype.initialize.apply(
        this,
        [
            {
                ...opts,
                hasStar: true
            },
            ...args
        ]
    );
}
```

This will:
1. Take first arg and change its prop `hasStar` *without* modifying source object
2. Pass all args including modified first one to `initialize`

Answer (score -1):

In first case, `eslint` is trying to avoid modifications in your function argument, which is a bad habit called `side effect`.

Second case, `eslint` is trying to avoid you to use arguments once `spread operator` is up to use.

Wrong:

```
initialize(opts) {
  opts.hasStar = true;
  AbstractResultView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

There are various ways to do it right. I' would try make it this way:

```
initialize(...args) {
  AbstractResultView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, args);
}

initialize(opts); // call method
opts.hasStar = true; // after assign a prop to it
```

All of this is by `eslint` point of view. You can supress this warning and continue doing your code if you would like to.

Comment: What's that `hasStar();` call?

Comment: I'm supposing hasStart prop from args are being setting to true in order to decide if or not call certain chunk of code. He could insert that chunk of code inside this method

Comment: I was not comfortable with this approach so I changed it.

Comment: Ah, that would totally make sense, it just depends on what the super call does.

Comment: I agree that relying on side effects is bad practice but like I said, this is not my code, I am only trying to fix it. Ufortunatelly, it looks like the active use of side effects is deeply embeded in this code (as this is hardly the only place where I have found it) and it would take a lot of rewrite to address it. So I think for now I will just tell ESLint to ignore these functions.

Answer (score -1):

Eventually, I found a solution that resolves both issues:

```
 8  initialize(...args) {
 9    // with destructuring:
10    const [opts] = args;  
11    // or without desctructuring:
12    // const opts = args[0];
13    opts.hasStar = true;
14    AbstractResultView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, args);
15  }
```

Comment: This solution actually modifies incoming object - the problem from which eslint rule was supposed to defend you. See my answer how to do it safe.